# Set UITableViewCell selected before presenting

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableViewCell that I want to show as selected when the UIViewController is presented. `vc.tableView.selectRow:atIndexPath` is nice in theory but it bypasses the calls for `willSelect` and `didSelect` on the cell.

The cell has an exposed UIImageView that `setSelected` toggles, which is what I'm trying to show on the initial load.

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example of how change background color of your cells and select a initial one, so you can follow and put the code that you need:

In your `UIViewController` subclass, implement these methods, so you can put your logic for selected and deselected states:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    deselectedCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

In your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass you have to override the `isSelected` property, this is the key to avoid the method `tableView.selectRow:atIndexPath` bypassing `didSelect`:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override var isSelected: Bool {        
        didSet {
            print(isSelected.description)
            self.selectionStyle = .none
            if isSelected{
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Last, back to your `UIViewController` subclass, you can call `selectRow:atIndexPath` in your `viewDidLoad` method, for instance:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) , animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alexandre. The problem however is `tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) , animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)` skips `willSelect` and `didSelect` as per the docs

Comment: @ZackShapiro Yes, it skips. That's why I created a custom `UITableViewCell` and overrided `isSelected` property, you can put your logic in it, so it won't be bypassed when you call `tableView.selectRow(at:)`

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. My fault. I'll give that a try. Thanks!